# Tracking letters in text file with dictionaries

Tags: python, loops, file, dictionary, iteration

everyone!

Consider following code, please

Body of exercise:

> Read through a text file, line by line. Use a dict to keep track of
> how many times each vowel (a, e, i, o, and u) appears in the file.
> Print the resulting tabulation.

My code:

```
from io import StringIO

filename = StringIO('''For the last 2 years I managed to read more than
20 books. 3 of them were in Sci-Fi genre, almost 10 of them are self-help,
the rest of 15 are fiction.''')

def sum_int(filename):
    VOWELS = {}
    occasions = 0
    filename = filename.read().split()
    for word in filename:
        for letter in word:
            if letter in 'aeiou':
                occasions += 1
                VOWELS[letter] = occasions
    return VOWELS

print(sum_int(filename)) **#returns {'o': 41, 'e': 38, 'a': 37, 'i': 40}
```

The problem is apparent: **results of summing particular vowel in text are not correct at all.**

What is the problem with my code?

Comment: You have a single `occasions` variable for all the vowels. You need to just `VOWELS[letter] += 1`. But remember to initialize your `VOWELS` with zeros for each vowel.

Comment: `VOWELS.setdefault(letter, 0) VOWELS[letter] += 1`

Comment: @DanilaGanchar Can I go with VOWELS[letter] = VOWELS.get(letter, 0) + 1? It seems like they are both the same thing, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set all vowels to `0` upfront:

```
from io import StringIO

filename = StringIO('''For the last 2 years I managed to read more than
20 books. 3 of them were in Sci-Fi genre, almost 10 of them are self-help,
the rest of 15 are fiction.''')


def sum_int(filename):
    vowels = 'aeiou'
    result = {v: 0 for v in vowels}

    filename = filename.read().split()
    for word in filename:
        for letter in word:
            if letter in vowels:
                result[letter] += 1
    return result


print(sum_int(filename))
```

Out:

```
{'a': 9, 'e': 17, 'i': 5, 'o': 10, 'u': 0}
```

Comment: Can I go with `VOWELS[letter] = VOWELS.get(letter, 0) + 1`?

Comment: ... why make it more complicated and less performant as it is :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You can just add 1 to the dictionary value if you encounter the letter. Since, a `KeyError` can be raised, it means that the key, value pair is not present. So, you can initalise the key.

```
from io import StringIO

filename = StringIO('''For the last 2 years I managed to read more than
20 books. 3 of them were in Sci-Fi genre, almost 10 of them are self-help,
the rest of 15 are fiction.''')

def sum_int(filename):
    VOWELS = {}
    
    filename = filename.read().split()
    for word in filename:
        for letter in word:
            if letter in 'aeiou':
                if letter in VOWELS:
                    VOWELS[letter] +=1
                else:
                    VOWELS[letter]=1
    return VOWELS

print(sum_int(filename))
```

Answer (score 1):

The comment by @YevhenKuzmovych is exactly right. But let me amplify his remark and make some suggestions.

In your loop you have:

```py
occasions += 1
```

This is being incremented for every occurrence of a vowel and thus maintains a total count of all vowels. It is clearly wrong to be using this as the count for a specific vowel. I would also rename this to `vowel_count`.

There is also no need to split the input into words and iterate first on words and then on the letters in each word. You can just iterate on all the letters on the entire input string. Also, what is being passed to function `sum_int` (what does this name mean?) is not a file name, which would then need to be opened, but rather an already opened stream. Thus we have:

```py
from io import StringIO

stream = StringIO('''For the last 2 years I managed to read more than
20 books. 3 of them were in Sci-Fi genre, almost 10 of them are self-help,
the rest of 15 are fiction.''')

def count_vowels(stream):
    vowels = dict(a=0, e=0, i=0, o=0, u=0)
    #vowel_count = 0
    s = stream.read()
    for ch in s:
        if ch in 'aeiou':
            #vowel_count += 1
            vowels[ch] += 1
    return vowels
print(count_vowels(stream))
```

Prints:

```
{'a': 9, 'e': 17, 'i': 5, 'o': 10, 'u': 0}
```

Or you can use the `collections.Counter` class:

```py
from io import StringIO
from collections import Counter

stream = StringIO('''For the last 2 years I managed to read more than
20 books. 3 of them were in Sci-Fi genre, almost 10 of them are self-help,
the rest of 15 are fiction.''')

def count_vowels(stream):
    vowels = Counter()
    #vowel_count = 0
    s = stream.read()
    for ch in s:
        if ch in 'aeiou':
            #vowel_count += 1
            vowels[ch] += 1
    return vowels
counts = count_vowels(stream)
for vowel in 'aeiou':
    print (vowel, '->', counts[vowel])
```

Prints:

```
a -> 9
e -> 17
i -> 5
o -> 10
u -> 0
```

**Notes**

`s` is the entire string and `ch` represents each character in the string whether it is a letter or space or punctuation mark such as a period. So you are inspecting each character and just selecting the vowels.

It is inefficient to first break up the string into *quasi* or *psuedo* words using `split`. I say *quasi* words because what you end up after removing the white space are not truly words because you still have punctuation marks appended to some of the words. Also the `split` just removes spaces and ends up creating a list of these quasi words and takes up additional time and space to do this (this is not a big issue if your input string is not too large but creates needless additional overhead especially for large input). Then you are forced to perform a double loop, first on each quasi word and then on each character in the quasi word. That is not as efficient as performing a single loop for each character in the initial string.

Comment: It is interesting how you iterate through file and picking characters without iterating through words themselves. I always thought of need to iterate through words in text, then letters in word. How `for ch in s` doesn't iterate through words in text but letter in words?

Comment: I have updated by appending a Notes section to answer you question.

Comment: I say `split` creates *quasi* or *pseudo* words because if you needed to pick the words out of the string to look up in a dictionary, then `split` is not adequate to do that for you because of the punctuation marks that will be attached to some of the results. So you are really *not* iterating words anyway.